# Using encrypted variable with Ansible-Vault for network automation

Tags: encryption, automation, ansible, cisco, ansible-vault

I have searched lots of tutorials on web & Youtube, but no luck.

I want to configure Cisco switch via Ansible, I already have it setup, works flawlessly.. but I want to store the passwords (for vty lines, console, enable secret...) ideally in **hosts** file encrypted via Ansible-Vault as variables so in my .yml file I can access them. I want them in hosts file, because we have different passwords for ASW, DSW and CSW so it could be easier to manage.

**I generated encrypted variable in CLI:**

```
ansible-vault encrypt_string enable_password --ask-vault-pass
```

I copy the value to the variable in **/etc/ansible/hosts:**

```
...
[2960-X:vars]
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=enable
ansible_network_os=ios
ansible_user=admin
enable_password= !vault |
     $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
     .....
```

In **config.yml:**

```
   - name: Set enable password
     ios_config:
       lines:
         - enable secret "{{ enable_password }}"
```

Right now, the password is going to be set as " !vault |" 
I am not sure if this is even best practise, I read recommendations for this but all I could find was about server automation, not networks.

I'm running Ansible 2.8.0

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me quote from [Variables and Vaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#variables-and-vaults)

> When running a playbook, Ansible finds the variables in the unencrypted file and all sensitive variables come from the encrypted file.
>
> A **best practice** approach for this is to start with a group_vars/ subdirectory named after the group. Inside of this subdirectory, create two files named **vars** and **vault**. Inside of the vars file, define all of the variables needed, including any sensitive ones. Next, **copy all of the sensitive variables over to the vault file and prefix these variables with vault_**. You should **adjust the variables in the vars file to point to the matching vault_ variables** using jinja2 syntax, and **ensure that the vault file is vault encrypted**.

This scheme isn't limited to group_vars/ only and can be applied to any place where the variables come from.